# How to format 04Apr with a single call to format()

Tags: javascript, format, momentjs

I'm trying to output the string `2015 - 04Apr - 15Wed`.

The closest I've come to was with `moment('2015-04-15').format('YYYY - MM MMM - DDddd')`, which outputs `2015 - 04 Apr - 15 Wed`.

How can I remove the space between `04` and `Apr` without calling `format()` twice?

The resulting string must contain ASCII characters only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the zero width space character `\u200B`.

```js
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= moment('2015-04-15').format('YYYY - MM\u200BMMM - DDddd')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Note:
this answer was before the change in requirement to ASCII characters only. I'm leaving it up as it may be useful to others who just need to display the date and not send the data back to a server.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use that. But using this unicode character feels wrong somehow. I'm starting to see the effect in that a url is being composed with the resulting string to retrieve a file, and this unicode character is getting transferred to the server as well. Not good (sorry, will remove the accept for this)

Answer (score 1):

Why the rule of not calling format more than once?  Both of these return the expected string.

```
var input = '2015-04-15';
var output = moment(input).format('YYYY - MM~MMMM - DDdddd').replace(/~/, '');
```

or

```
var input = '2015-04-15';
var output = moment(input).format('YYYY - MM') + moment(input).format('MMM - DDddd');
```